# how to Set $PATH for all users on centos?

Tags: centos

I'm new to CentOS, I want to add something to $PATH, so I use the command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/scala/bin
```

But, it just set path for any one particular user. I want to set $PATH for all users. Then I find it can work using that:

```
vi /etc/profile 
       JAVA_HOME=/usr/java
       PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
       export JAVA_HOME PATH
source /etc/profile
```

Can anyone just using command to do it. Because I want to write Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're asking specifically if anyone can use it?  In general, users don't have to `source /etc/profile`, but anyone with "normal" privileges should be able to do so.

Also, you are correct that /etc/profile is **usually** executed for all users.  You might want to ensure that the Docker is behaving as you expect; see the following on times when /etc/profile may not be sourced: [/etc/profile not sourced](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16588).  In the referenced page, there is a spot where you can put commands that **every** bash invocation **should** pick up: `/etc/profile.d/myscript.sh`